# How to preserve original characters (encoding) when writing to file in different operating systems?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding

I have a script that converts files from HTML to JSON and vice versa.
The problem arises when I test my script on different operating systems (the main problem being windows).

I test the code by having a copy of the expected result in a `result.json` file, and comparing it to the output `output.json`.
That is when some characters end up converted to weird symbols. and of course the test fails. (**NOTE:** this only happens in Windows, both Linux and macOS pass the tests.)

The following are the problematic symbols I have encountered:

| Original Character | Windows resulting symbol |
| --- | --- |
| `’` | `�` |
| `–` | `�` |
| `·` | `�` |
| `|` | `�|�` |

Below are the functions that I use to read the content of the files to my script:

```py
with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as input_file, 
     open(output_filepath, "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:

    for line in input_file:
        # some string manipulation with .replace() and .strip()
        output_file.write(line)

# I then read the contents again using beautifulsoup
with open(self.temp_filepath, "r") as file_:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        markup=file_,
        features="html.parser",
        from_encoding="Utf-8",
        element_classes={Tag: HTMLBookmark},
    )
```

Finally after modifying things with my script I write the content to a JSON file as follows:

```py
with open(output_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file_:
    json.dump(data, file_, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Any idea on how I can get the content of the output file to always be the same (showing the original character preferably) in all operating systems?

Here is a link to the GitHub actions were the windows test fails. [Link](https://github.com/radam9/bookmarks_parser/runs/1717416002?check_suite_focus=true)

And this is the code in `pytest` that checks that the files are identical:

```py
with open(result_file, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as orig, open(
    output_file, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as new:

    assert orig.readline() == new.readline()
```

**EDIT:** I changed the hexdumps, the first hexdump is from the original `HTML` file and the second hexdump is from the resulting output `JSON` file.

This is the result of `hexdump -s -C` on the output file, for some reason it is not showing the correct text on the right side (maybe I am using a wrong parameter for hexdump?) but the first `code block` contains the correct text from the source `HTML` file, while the second `code block` contains the bad text from the output `JSON` file.
The part that is wrong is the `It’s what’s happening` which is showing as `It�s what�s happening`.

```
00000a30  54 6b 53 75 51 6d 43 43  22 3e 54 77 69 74 74 65  |TkSuQmCC">Twitte|
00000a40  72 2e 20 49 74 e2 80 99  73 20 77 68 61 74 e2 80  |r. It...s what..|
00000a50  99 73 20 68 61 70 70 65  6e 69 6e 67 20 2f 20 54  |.s happening / T|
00000a60  77 69 74 74 65 72 3c 2f  41 3e 0d 0a 20 20 20 20  |witter</A>..    |
00000a70  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  3c 44 54 3e 3c 41 20 48  |        <DT><A H|
00000a80  52 45 46 3d 22 68 74 74  70 73 3a 2f 2f 77 77 77  |REF="https://www|
00000a90  2e 66 61 63 65 62 6f 6f  6b 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 22 20  |.facebook.com/" |
00000aa0  41 44 44 5f 44 41 54 45  3d 22 31 35 39 39 37 35  |ADD_DATE="159975|
00000ab0  30 38 30 37 22 20 49 43  4f 4e 3d 22 64 61 74 61  |0807" ICON="data|
00000ac0  3a 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 70  6e 67 3b 62 61 73 65 36  |:image/png;base6|
```

```
00000730  6c 65 22 3a 20 22 54 77  69 74 74 65 72 2e 20 49  |le": "Twitter. I|
00000740  74 c3 a2 e2 82 ac e2 84  a2 73 20 77 68 61 74 c3  |t........s what.|
00000750  a2 e2 82 ac e2 84 a2 73  20 68 61 70 70 65 6e 69  |.......s happeni|
00000760  6e 67 20 2f 20 54 77 69  74 74 65 72 22 2c 20 22  |ng / Twitter", "|
00000770  64 61 74 65 5f 61 64 64  65 64 22 3a 20 31 35 39  |date_added": 159|
00000780  39 37 35 30 37 39 35 2c  20 22 75 72 6c 22 3a 20  |9750795, "url": |
00000790  22 68 74 74 70 73 3a 2f  2f 74 77 69 74 74 65 72  |"https://twitter|
000007a0  2e 63 6f 6d 2f 3f 6c 61  6e 67 3d 65 6e 22 2c 20  |.com/?lang=en", |
000007b0  22 69 63 6f 6e 22 3a 20  22 64 61 74 61 3a 69 6d  |"icon": "data:im|
000007c0  61 67 65 2f 70 6e 67 3b  62 61 73 65 36 34 2c 69  |age/png;base64,i|
```

Comment: It looks to me that as if the characters have been preserved, but that the program you are you using to look at the file is unable to display the characters. A simple way to check this is open your output file in Windows++ (free to download from https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) . It is very good at encodings.

Comment: We can’t tell you the correct encoding without seeing (a representative, ideally small sample of) the actual contents of the data in an unambiguous representation; a hex dump of the problematic byte(s) with a few bytes of context on each side is often enough, especially if you can tell us what you think those bytes are supposed to represent. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: @BoarGules , I am not opening the file with any application, the error is happening from the pytest.

Comment: @tripleee , I will add a link to the GitHub Actions that is causing the error to the thread.

Comment: @Adam What error? It looks like this is just a font issue on windows. Whatever program you're using to view the output is using a font that doesn't include support for certain non-ascii characters. Or possibly it just doesn't know how to handle utf-8 properly at all.

Comment: I don't understand what *from the pytest* means. But the real check is to *actually look at the output file* and not rely on some other process to tell you what is in it. It could be that your test report is expecting ascii input.

Comment: The pytest just compares the contents of both files, either with an `assert` in a loop or with `filecmp.cmp()`. I am currently on my phone so I can really add the code that tests the files, I will add that when I get home.

Comment: @Adam The 1st character (`’`) is U+2019. In utf-8, this would be encoded as `b'\xe2\x80\x99'`, but in e.g. windows-1252 it would be `b'\x92'`. You need to look at the bytes of the original file to see what encoding is being used. (Similarly, the 2nd character (`–`) is U+2013, utf-8=`b'\xe2\x80\x93'`, windows-1252=`b'\x96'`). If the file is properly encoded as utf-8, you will know this is a problem with whatever program you are passing the output to (i.e. it's not able to detect the original encoding properly).

Comment: @Adam PS: you should also verify that BeautifulSoup is handling the encdoing correctly. This can be done by checking the value of `soup.original_encoding` and `soup.contains_replacement_characters` (see [here for more details](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings)). Alternatively, you could check whether the output contains any `b'\xfffd'` characters.

Comment: @ekhumoro , I am not opening the file with any other program as stated in the previous comment, beautifulsoup is not the problem as the tests pass fine on Linux and macOS

Comment: @Adam Yes, you are. The program that runs the tests is obviously opening the files, otherwise how would you know there was an issue?

Comment: @ekhumoro , I am not running the tests using any program, the tests are being run by pytest, I have added the code that checks that the files are identical (the same code that fails the test)

Comment: @tripleee , I have added a hexdump output, I don't know if this is the kind of hex dump you are talking about. do guide me if there is something wrong with what I provided.

Comment: @Adam pytest clearly **is** a program. Have you done any basic debugging? The test `assert orig.readline() == new.readline()` seems unnecessairly crude. You should use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) to see exactly where the differences are.

Comment: @ekhumoro , I use `filecmp.cmp()` to compare the 2 files, but because that function doesn't show the text when it fails, I used the `assert` in the loop instead. I currently don't have a windows pc available to test on, so all the windows tests are done on `Github Actions`

Comment: @Adam The first hexdump has replacement characters in it: i.e. `ef bf bd`, which equates to `b'\xfffd'`. As I pointed out above, this may have been done by BeautifulSoup. You open the file in text mode *without specifying an encoding*, so this will default to `locale.getpreferredencoding()` - which may not be utf-8 (depending on the system). Always specify the correct encoding when using `open` in text mode; or use bytes mode (`'rb'`) when passing it to something that is able to guess the encoding (such as BeautifulSoup).

Comment: The hex dump looks good yeah, thanks for that. It's not at all clear to me where the corruption happens but U+FFFD is Unicode's way of telling you that you specified an invalid encoding or that the input simply cannot be represented as Unicode. The link to the failing test is less useful than a description of what *exactly* the test actually does, and a [mre] allowing us to reproduce that outside of `pytest` and ideally without needing to scrape innocent third-party sites.

Comment: @ekhumoro , I have specified the encoding in all the instances I have opened a file, whether by `open()` or by `beautifulsoup()`

Comment: But what are the _actual_ characters on the original page, and are you sure you are saving them correctly?

Comment: @tripleee , the _actual characters_ are the ones I posted in the table, they are in an _HTML_ or _JSON_ files. reading and writing to the files is done using the code snippets I posted on top, I always specify that I am reading and writing using _utf-8_. I think I just got my hands on a windows laptop I can somehow use, I will try to get the resulting file to check for its encoding, and post a new hexdump it is different.

Comment: @tripleee , I updated the hexdumps , the first one corresponds to the source _HTML_ file while the second one corresponds to the output _JSON_ file. If there are any checks you want me to run on the original and output file, let me know.

Comment: This now looks like *bona fide* [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) where somewhere along the line something thought text which was already UTF-8 needed to be converted from Windows-1252 (I guess) to UTF-8. For example, `e2 80 99` in `it...s` is the UTF-8 encoding of `’` but if interpreted as Windows-1252, it would display as `â€™` which is what `c3 a2 e2 82 ac e2 84 a2` in the second hex dump decodes to. I can't guess from your code which file contains what; we'd still need debugging details.

Comment: @tripleee , would this occur even if I pass the `encoding="utf-8"` to all the `open()` and `BeautifulSoup()` functions ?

Comment: If you can pare this down to a [mre] where the input file simply contains the three bytes e2 80 99 you should be able to find in your code when the contents change from the expected character `’` to something else.

Comment: Your `encoding="utf-8"` looks correct everywhere but I was wondering whether BeautifulSoup would still somehow manage to produce the wrong result if the input HTML has a `meta` tag which overrides what you pass in, or something.

Comment: @tripleee , the `meta` tag in the _HTML_ file is also _UTF-8_ , I will recheck the code everywhere to check if I missed adding `encoding="utf-8"` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I want to thank @tripleee and @ekhumoro as I was able to find the problem and learn a lot thanks to their comments.

The issue was as stated by @ekhumoro ([comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763646/how-to-preserve-original-characters-encoding-when-writing-to-file-in-different?noredirect=1#comment116279650_65763646)) and @tripleee ([comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763646/how-to-preserve-original-characters-encoding-when-writing-to-file-in-different?noredirect=1#comment116290070_65763646)), a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).
As shown in the question's first code snippet:

```py
# original code snippet from questions
with open(self.temp_filepath, "r") as file_:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        markup=file_,
        features="html.parser",
        from_encoding="Utf-8",
        element_classes={Tag: HTMLBookmark},
    )

# correct code snippet
with open(self.temp_filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file_:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        markup=file_,
        features="html.parser",
        from_encoding="Utf-8",
        element_classes={Tag: HTMLBookmark},
    )
```

there was a missing `encoding="utf-8"`. which caused all the problems.

Comment: I already [explained exactly what the problem was and how to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763646/how-to-preserve-original-characters-encoding-when-writing-to-file-in-different?noredirect=1#comment116279650_65763646) earlier. When you open a file in **text mode** without specifying an encoding, it will default to the preferred encoding for the locale - which on Windows is **not utf-8**.

Comment: @ekhumoro , yes you did, but I did not notice the 1 `open()` in my code that was missing the `encoding="utf-8"` since I have about 10 `open()` functions.

Comment: Okay. There's only one in your question that has it missing, though, and that's also the only one that gets passed to BeautifulSoup. Perhaps I should have spelled that out more clearly in my comments.